# Laravel Error Message in view directive @error appears for other update form

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, session-variables, laravel-blade

I am new a Laravel, my issue is that error message still showing up in other modal form, my crud is a table with edit buttons for each row (each register).

I am working with $errors, I have a modal with a form and it does display error message if I am trying to update it in an incorrect way (missing a input, etc) , I redisplay those errors using a session variable in order to re-open the modal (query) and show the errors.

**But if i don't re-submit it actually update the register , and i click the button to see another update modal form (for a different register) the error will appears, event though I am trying to forget session variable in the Controller function(variable thay I used as condition to display errors in html)**

**Controller**

```php
public function show($id)
{
    session()->forget('errorUpdateTicket');
    $ticket = Ticket::findOrFail($id);

    return $ticket->toJson();
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules, $this->message);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('incidents')
            ->with('errorUpdateTicket', 'errorUpdateTicket')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
}
```

View error message

```
@if(session('errorUpdateTicket'))
    @error('category_id')
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
<strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
</span>
    @enderror
@endif
```

The main trouble is that I would like to close the modal and open another register to update and it shouldn't appear those errors, I know that the trouble is that $errors and session ('errorUpdateTicket') still have old values, but I don't know in which way I can delete them, I guess in the function that show register data but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$request->session()->flash('errorUpdateTicket', 'errorUpdateTicket');`

Comment: It keeps the error as the flash keeps the session variable until a new request is done. I am just doing another get request and it shows the error in other modals (modals that I show up ussing a button) .

Comment: I did solve it in a way I don't like it. In jquery when I click the button I remove 'is-invalid' class (class use in laravel view to show the:$errors message) for all input and select  . Code :    $('#modal-update-ticket input').removeClass('is-invalid');
  $('#modal-update-ticket select').removeClass('is-invalid');).

Comment: Sry I just the question again. I think the only problem is that you are using the same modal for every button. Ofc you have to use js to change the content of that modal if you want the message to disappear. Your way is correct actually but this is not a laravel problem.